# How to get database records only with filled field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have model with an optional `ForeignKey` field. I need filter all records with filled this field. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model.objects.exclude(foreignkey__isnull=True)
```

or

```
Model.objects.filter(foreignkey__isnull=False)
```